# Difference between rmdir and rm -r

Tags: directory, rm, command

I usually delete directories by using [rm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html):

```
rm -r myDir
```

However I am aware of another command, [rmdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html), which seems to do the job just as well:

```
rmdir myDir
```

What is the difference between these two commands and when should each be used?

Comment: Does your rmdir work if there are files in the subdirectory?

Comment: See also the eponymous system call [`rmdir(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/rmdir) which can only remove empty directories.

Comment: By the way, there's a "correct" procedure for using `rm -r`:  (1) Type in the command, but don't enter it (2) Take your hands away from the keyboard (3) Count to five (4) Hit ENTER.  I've started doing something like this with all dangerous commands, to give me a chance to look at what I'm doing, make sure I typed things in correctly, think about whether  there could be unexpected consequences, etc.  Occasionally this leads me to erase my command and do some extra checks first, for example.

Comment: @ajb `rm -rf ~ /*` - clean out my home directory. Or wait, maybe clean out the system. Always good to double check ;).

Comment: @ajb or, since I prefer to be lazy and not waste time `rm () { echo -n "rm $*? (yes/no) ";
    read ip;
    if [[ $ip == "yes" ]]; then
        echo; /bin/rm -v "$@";
    fi
}`

Comment: @cat You're making me type in three extra letters.  Sorry, I'm too lazy to do that.  :)

Comment: @ajb Notice that `rmdir` and `rm -r` are two strings _of the same length_  :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`rm -r` removes a directory and all its contents; `rmdir` will only remove a directory if the directory is empty.  I like to use the following to remove a directory and all its contents:

```
rm -r <directory_to_be_removed>
```

Sometimes there might be repeated prompts while removing files :  `remove write-protected regular file ... ?` To avoid entering `y` every time, one can force using `-f`:

```
rm -rf <directory_to_be_forcefully_removed>
```

Comment: Note, that you usually should not use ``-f`` if you do not need to. Its handy to use ``-rf`` every time, but it disables (almost) all safety checks.

Comment: -1 for uneccesary recommendation of rm's `-f` flag which can have unforeseeable, unrevertable consequences

Comment: So `rmdir` is just `rm -d`?

Comment: @StanStrum `-d` is not a standard option to `rm`.

Comment: @cat The `rm` command _in general_ may have these consequences. The `-f` flag is useful when running under `set -e` in a script. I'd agree that using without thinking is _unnecessary_.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `rm -r` when wanting to recursively remove a directory and all its contents, or when the target may be a directory or file and you want to delete it regardless of what it is.

You should use `rmdir` when wanting to remove an empty directory.

The `rmdir` command is useful since it refuses to remove non-empty directories and files.  This serves as a safety catch in situations where you may want to be absolutely sure that what you're deleting is a directory and that the directory is empty before deleting it (for example in a script) and want to treat it as an error condition otherwise.